# jquery focusout on a textbox in partial view asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Want to fire alert when somebody leaves the textbox that is in a partial view in a asp.net mvc 4 application.
Wont work for me. no error just not working. my code
Jquery

```
$("#username").on('focusout', 'input', function () {
    alert("Lost Focus");
});
```

Html in the partial View

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-6 control-label forms">UserName</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3 input-container">
        <input type="text" name="Username" id="username"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to attach the event handler to an element that does not exist. (You filter your `#username` element's descendants with the `input` selector, so basically what you are saying to jquery is "bind the `focusout` handler to the descendants of `#username` that match the `input` selector". See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more info.)

This will work:

```
$("#username").on('focusout', function () {
   alert("Lost Focus");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#username').focusout(function(){
        alert('lost focus!');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fc4mpo1w/6/